# how to convert these things back to raw text?

Tags: php, html

i use curl to fetch a page's source, it works great but not the inside html, it's returned with something like this :

the html look like this :  t i & # 7 8 7 1; t, #&&#%$^%, etc....

yes, i really want to convert it to normal text, i try php decode functions but there's no luck at all

Thank you

##################3

edit :
thank you sirs,i tried 
$fixed_result = html_entity_decode($result, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
and it works like a charm, but there are some character become "�", as this :
" S�C KH�CH"

i have no idea what is this
thank you sirs

Comment: have you tried `html_entity_decode`?

Comment: yes , i have but the source it still the same

Comment: Show some code. Html entity decode behaves differently for different encodings, perhaps you were 'nearly there', since it is definitely the way to go.

Comment: What is your third parameter, charset?

Comment: hmmm... mobiphone promotion. hacking?

Comment: no , i just want to look for the new bonus program from their home page for users, this is a totally friendly script.

Comment: " S�C KH�CH" - this is happening because some versions of PHP cant handle unicode chars.  Check your version of PHP and upgrade if necessary

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be HTML entity encoded, you should be able to revert to the normal characters using [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) with the appropriate character set specified. e.g.:

```
$fixed_result = html_entity_decode($result, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: thank you sir, this works like a charm, but there's a problem with some character, it becomes " S�C KH�CH", i mean how can i decode the "�"

Comment: the code is valided display on browser, but the html source is decoded as i mention when i open it in notepad, i use the html source to work as a part of my php script, so i need it totally normally, thank you sir

Comment: @Ryo: some older versions of notepad cannot display UTF-8 encoded text. You can try opening the file in Wordpad -- or better yet, a real editor.

Comment: oh, the problem is actually solved at first with your code, it was just my mistake for the second question. Thank you sir, you make my day !

Answer (score 0):

As per ajreal's comment check the manual for `html_entity_decode` and try the fallback solution:

```
// For users prior to PHP 4.3.0 you may do this:
function unhtmlentities($string)
{
    // replace numeric entities
    $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
    // replace literal entities
    $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
    return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
}

$c = unhtmlentities($a);
```

(edit) For multi-byte support try the following version, taken from the PHP comments page,

```
function unhtmlentities($string)
{
    // replace numeric entities
    $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'code2utf(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'code2utf("\\1")', $string);
    // replace literal entities
    $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
    return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
}

// Returns the utf string corresponding to the unicode value (from php.net, courtesy - romans@void.lv)
function code2utf($num)
{
    if ($num < 128) return chr($num);
    if ($num < 2048) return chr(($num >> 6) + 192) . chr(($num & 63) + 128);
    if ($num < 65536) return chr(($num >> 12) + 224) . chr((($num >> 6) & 63) + 128) . chr(($num & 63) + 128);
    if ($num < 2097152) return chr(($num >> 18) + 240) . chr((($num >> 12) & 63) + 128) . chr((($num >> 6) & 63) + 128) . chr(($num & 63) + 128);
    return '';
}

$c = unhtmlentities($a);
```

Comment: This does not work for multi-byte character encodings as `chr` does only work with bytes (0–255).

Comment: @Gumbo, ok I see further examples in the comments on the PHP page giving workarounds for Unicode `chr()` implementations.